# Merge Rows with Same ID but Different Column Values in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Im trying to merge rows into one based on a ID Number that has different column values. In this example I am creating new column values based on Case statements. Please see my code below and actual results versus expected. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT *

FROM (
SELECT CTR_NMBR, CODE, EXEC_ID,

CASE
  WHEN CODE = '2_EXEC_ZERO'
  THEN 2
  Else NULL
END AS Exclude_Zero,

CASE
  WHEN CODE = '3_EXEC_MAT'
  THEN 3
  Else NULL
END AS Exclude_Mat

FROM EXCLUDED)

WHERE COALESCE(Exclude_Zero, Exclude_Mat) IS NOT NULL;
```

Actual Results:

```
CTR_NMBR        CODE            EXEC_ID         Exclude_Zero        Exclude_Mat 
E0105753       2_EXEC_ZERO       565                2
E0105753       3_EXEC_MAT        565                                    3
```

Expected Results:

```
CTR_NMBR        EXEC_ID         Exclude_Zero        Exclude_Mat
E0105753         565                2                    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT CTR_NMBR, EXEC_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODE = '2_EXEC_ZERO' THEN 2
           END) AS Exclude_Zero,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CODE = '3_EXEC_MAT' THEN 3
           END) AS Exclude_Mat
FROM EXCLUDED
GROUP BY CTR_NMBR, EXEC_ID;
```

Comment: @Manny . . . True, but this answer was posted five minutes before that one.

Answer (score 1):

remove `code` from selection and do conditional aggregation

```
SELECT CTR_NMBR, EXEC_ID,

 max(CASE
  WHEN CODE = '2_EXEC_ZERO'
  THEN 2 end)      
 AS Exclude_Zero,

 max( CASE
  WHEN CODE = '3_EXEC_MAT'
  THEN 3 end) AS Exclude_Mat

FROM EXCLUDED group by CTR_NMBR, EXEC_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `decode` with `aggregation` by using `regex` to extract the digit dynamically from `code` column

```
with excluded(ctr_nmbr, code, exec_id ) as
(
 select 'E0105753', '2_EXEC_ZERO', 565 from dual union all
 select 'E0105753',  '3_EXEC_MAT', 565 from dual   
)
select ctr_nmbr, exec_id,
       max(decode(code,'2_EXEC_ZERO',regexp_substr(code,'[^_]+',1),null)) as Exclude_Zero,
       max(decode(code,'3_EXEC_MAT',regexp_substr(code,'[^_]+',1),null)) as Exclude_Mat           
  from excluded
 group by ctr_nmbr, exec_id;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/EUGJPX35783)</kbd>